# Lisp DO variable syntax reasoning

Tags: syntax, lisp, let, do-loops

In Peter Seibel's *Practical Common Lisp*, he gives this example:

```
(do ((nums nil) (i 1 (1+ i)))
    ((> i 10) (nreverse nums))
  (push i nums))
```

I can see how it works, using nums inside the loop but not giving it a step-form.  Why would you put nums in the variable-definition rather than do this:

```
(let (nums) (do ((i 1 (+ i 1)))
         ((> i 10) (nreverse nums))
       (push i nums)))
```

I'm sure there's a good reason, but I don't get it yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it's convenient and saves indentation.  Furthermore, the accumulator conceptually belongs to the loop, so why not put it there?